# SQL auto_increment id randomly jumping after switching servers

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, auto-increment

I developed my website on Godaddy then moved it over to MediaTemple. After doing so when a new entry is inserted on this table the auto increment id is no longer in increments of 1. The first ten entries were added while on the old server and are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, and 10. After moving the database to the new server the next id was 55, then 108, 136, 182, and 190.

This only happens with this one table and happens when an entry is inserted via php/pdo or phpmyadmin. The other tables still add ids in increments of one.

Here are some screenshots of the table's structure.

[drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Tpq5uOpTLFakt2N3JlYk9Lams/view?usp=sharing](http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Tpq5uOpTLFakt2N3JlYk9Lams/view?usp=sharing)

[drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Tpq5uOpTLFRW9DNlJUa2pld0k/view?usp=sharing](http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Tpq5uOpTLFRW9DNlJUa2pld0k/view?usp=sharing)

[drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Tpq5uOpTLFOGdybXZHWTE5dE0/view?usp=sharing](http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Tpq5uOpTLFOGdybXZHWTE5dE0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you share create table syntax of that table

Comment: Here is the syntax from exporting the structure...

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `twitter` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `info` text NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zip` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `posted_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `url_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=267 ;

Comment: Check your INCREMENT by this command on your new server: `SELECT @@auto_increment_increment;`.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `events`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`url_name`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `events`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=267;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;

Comment: @BALAJI I assume you mean "AUTO_INCREMENT=267"?

Would you know a SQL command to change that? And do you know what the 267 means/does?

Comment: This will have next auto_increment value as 267. `ALTER TABLE events AUTO_INCREMENT = {your_value}`

Comment: Yes, it is where your AUTO_INCREMENT starts. Nothing but a seed value and the command `SELECT @@auto_increment_increment;` shows the increment value by which the next increment takes place.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your `@@auto_increment_increment` value is getting changed from somewhere. So my suggestion is that please check it by using this command,

```
SELECT @@auto_increment_increment;
```

And if it returns **1** then its fine if doesn't then set it like,

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
```

Also you can check it in Mysql configuration file, provided that you have permissions to access that file `\mysql\bin\my.ini`

Also you can change the seed value of AUTO_INCREMENT by,

```
ALTER your_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Oops, did not see the answer posted by you.

Comment: Thanks. This answer has more useful information than the one I posted. I would "vote up" but I need a reputation of 15+ to do so which I don't have yet since this is my first post.

Answer (score 0):

As shown from the export structure syntax the auto_increment was set to 267 somehow.

I used the query...

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=191
```

And this solved the issue. `190` was the last `id` so `191` would be next. Did a few tests and it is back to auto increments of one. I can only guess that the ids were doing big jumps in an attempt to reach `267` and that they would have went back to increments of one after reaching `267`. Just a guess.

Thanks to those who commented.